# Is there a term for this kind of wordplay (rhyming slang)?

Tags: slang, rhymes

Swapping the phonemes of often used phrases while keeping them the same size and structure, for example:

- Washing the Dishes -> Wishing the Dashes / Dashing the Wishes (or even Flushing the Fishes)
- Making Breakfast -> Braking Makefast
- Go to the shop -> Sho to the Gop (dictionary words not required, but preferred) / Flow to the Drop (completely removed from original)

I did not find a match on [this list of forms of world play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_forms_of_word_play). I'm guessing it might be a form of rhyming slang?

Comment: Hmm, off the top of my head, the closest I can come is *spoonerism*, as in "butterflies flutter by".

Comment: @DanBron 2 & 3 are definitely spoonerisms.  The first isn't (that would be "dashing the wishes" rather than "wishing the dashes".)

Comment: Most of these are **spoonerisms**. Others (like "Go to the shop" / "Flow to the drop") are just cases of **multiple-syllable rhyme**. "Washing the dishes"/"Wishing the dashes" might be called **intra-word spoonerism**.

Comment: Actually, reading about spoonerisms here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoonerism, it says "corresponding syllables are swapped" and doesn't specify that they have to be the **first** syllables.  So I think they can all be called spoonerisms.

Comment: The problem is spoonerisms and metathesis are essentially *spoken, verbal* transpositions. But something like *Wishing the Dashes* is really just an orthographic "pun", since in speech, ***wash*** and ***dash*** are only loosely related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your examples are heterogeneous. They do not form a natural kind. Let's take them one by one.

> *Washing the Dishes / Dashing the Wishes*

is an example of a ***[spoonerism](https://www.google.com/#q=define%20spoonerism)***, that is,

> a verbal error in which a speaker accidentally transposes the initial sounds or letters of two or more words, often to humorous effect.

Spoonerisms are typically *speech* errors, but the term can be used more broadly to mean an *orthographic* transposition that might even affect pronunciation.

Next,

> *Washing the Dishes / Wishing the Dashes*

might be called an ***intra-word spoonerism***, that is, the transposition of sounds or letters *within* two words.

> *Washing the Dishes / Flushing the fishes*

is an example of ***[multi-syllable rhyme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisyllabic_rhymes)*** where the first pair "washing/flushing" are only ***[slant rhymed](https://www.google.com/#q=slant+rhyme)***. The second pair "dishes/fishes" are ***[full rhymed](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/full-rhyme)***.

> *Making Breakfast / Braking Makefast*

is another example of a spoonerism.

> *Go to the Shop / Sho to the Gop*

is also an example of a spoonerism.

> *Go to the Shop / Flow to the Drop*

is another example of multi-syllable rhyme. Here, the pairs are comprised of ***[full rhymes](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/full-rhyme)*** ("go/flow" and "shop/drop").